# how to uncompress an ARM "vmlinuz" kernel?

Tags: arm, kernel, compression

I'm a longtime Debian's user (lover?) and I just get à Raspberry Pi 3+. I would like to run Debian (instead of Raspbian) on it, I'm using debootstrap to install it on an usbkey. I've tried to boot on it and everything work except that I need to boot on an uncompressed kernel. (for the test I used the Rapsbian kernel but it doesn't match the Debian's modules so...)
The problem is that I can't find a solution to uncompress an ARM vmlinuz kernel  :(

This is the "best" method I've seen through my researches but it doesn't work with an ARM (only x86) :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mhhaque/entry/anatomy_of_the_initrd_and_vmlinuz?lang=en

When I try to gunzip I got this error : *gzip: unknown suffix -- ignored*

Someone can help ?

Thanks

K.

Comment: Have you tried to rename vmlinuz to something like vmlinux.gz, such that gunzip can recognize it as a gz-file?

Comment: the only "difference" I see regarding the method mentioned (link) before, is that the hexcode does not match the x86 one... I got "1f 8b 08 4a" instead of "1f 8b 08 00" and gzip doesn't like it...

Answer (score 0):

gunzip expects the file suffix to be ".gz" so it warns "unknown suffix -- ignored."

I have attempted to pass in flags like --force or --suffix "", but that doesn't work.

Here are some options to fix the issue

1. Rename the file to .gz
2. cat vmlinuz | gunzip > vmlinux
3. zcat vmlinuz > vmlinux